# Rampant false definition of orthohelium on the internet?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics, quantum-spin, fermions, spin-statistics

This is an extension of [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/188543/is-this-definition-of-orthohelium-and-parahelium-incorrect) question, which has no good answers (in my opinion) and seems to have been mostly ignored.

The correct definition of [orthohelium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helium_atom#Perturbation_method) seems to be any state of helium in which the electron **spin** part of the wavefunction is **symmetric** (hence the spatial part is antisymmetric, since electrons are fermions and so the overall wavefunction must be antisymmetric).

The symmetric two-spin wavefunctions are the three triplet states. Two triplet states have parallel-oriented spins, namely $|\uparrow\uparrow\rangle$ and $|\downarrow\downarrow\rangle$); one has anti-parallel spins, namely $\frac1{\sqrt2}\big(|\uparrow\downarrow\rangle+|\downarrow\uparrow\rangle\big)$.

Unless I'm making a silly mistake, half of the internet is wrong, claiming that orthohelium is a state with parallel spins [[1]](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/helium.html#c2) [[2]](https://wikidiff.com/parahelium/orthohelium) [[3]](https://encyclopedia2.thefreedictionary.com/orthohelium) [[4]](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/orthohelium) [[5]](https://definition.org/define/orthohelium/). Am I missing something here, or is everyone else?

Comment: Hmm, this might be a case of a standard (over)simplification suited for high schoolers and beginning chemistry majors. A lot of things in introductory chemistry are described in this kind of imprecise way, and the internet tends to cater to the introductory level.

Comment: You are basically asking if half the internet is wrong about something.  This seems like a trivial "yes", as the internet is full of stuff that's wrong, a lie, a mistake or even true.  I don't see a focused question here.

Comment: @StephenG It's trivial that the internet is "full of wrong stuff," but not whether one particular claim is wrong! Indeed, this one turned out to be subtle and perhaps correct under the right interpretation, as the answer and comments here reveal. Far from a trivial "yes, wrong" at any rate.

Answer (score 2):

The definition of orthohelium as having two parallel electron spins is correct. In the state $$\frac1{\sqrt2}\big(|\uparrow\downarrow\rangle+|\downarrow\uparrow\rangle\big)$$ the two spins are also parallel. It may seem that they are not, but note that this state has $m_z=0$, so both spins are perpendicular to the quantization direction. Indeed, the operator $S_+$ will turn this state into $$\big(|\uparrow\uparrow\rangle\big)$$.

Also, this is an eigenstate of $S^2$ with eigenvalue 2$\hbar^2$, just like the other members of the triplet, while $S_1 \cdot S_2$ has eigenvalue $+\frac{\hbar^2}{4}$. The positive sign indicates that the spins are parallel. Indeed for the singlet this eigenvalue is $-\frac{3\hbar^2}{4}$, which indicates antiparallel alignment.

Comment: But in this state, if I perform simultaneous measurements of the z-components of the spins of each particle, I'm guaranteed to get anti-parallel outcomes. Are you claiming that anti-parallel should be considered parallel, or something else?

Comment: Also I don't see the relevance of your last point. Why does it matter whether the spins are parallel after operating with $S_+$? I'm asking about the original state, not the post-$S_+$ state.

Comment: You have no basis for saying that the spins are antiparallel.

Comment: I think this has reduced to an issue of terminology. By anti-parallel spins, I meant that one was z-spin up and the other z-spin down. You seem to be defining spins to be antiparallel [parallel] iff they are in the $S=0$/singlet [$S=1$/triplet] state. Can you speak at all to why your definition is better or at least more conventional?

Comment: Perhaps the fact that we are using up and down arrows is confusing.

Comment: @WillG For another perspective: The representation in eigenvalues of $S_z$ is confusing here. Sinze $m_z = 0$, the state has to be entangled in a way that makes sure that when measuring $S_{1z}$ and $S_{2z}$ the sum is zero. This, however, has nothing to do with whether the spins are parallel or not. This is just a consequence of the fact that the spins lie in the $x$-$y$-plane. When measuring $S_z$ you ask them in the wrong basis.

Comment: @SebastianRiese Ok, but then should we expect $m_x=1$ or $m_y=1$, for the state $\frac1{\sqrt2}(|\uparrow\downarrow\rangle+|\downarrow\uparrow\rangle)$? I'm getting zero for those too, although maybe I made a mistake in calculating them.

Comment: The state is not an eigenstate of $L_x$ or $L_y$, you can read it off the expression in the $L_x$-eigenbasis it is given as $\frac 1 {\sqrt 2} \big( \lvert ++ \rangle + \lvert -- \rangle \big) $ (and similar for $y$). (My answer to the questions that this one was marked a duplicate of derives the representation in the $x$-basis).

Comment: @SebastianRiese Ah I see. $m_x=0$ because the state is a superposition of the eigenstates for which $m_x=+1$ and $m_x=-1$. And in both of those eigenstates, the two particles' $x$-spins are aligned.